# Integration of a complex exponential

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I would like to know how to integrate a function that looks like

$$ \int_{a<|x|<b} \frac{dx}{|x|^{-n-it}}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \, 0<a<b. $$

Thank you.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ real?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are integrating with respect to $t$ or $x$.

Comment: Yes a and b are real , I have corrected the integral.

Comment: Change to spherical coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$. The integral over the angles gives the surface area of a unit $(n - 1)$-sphere.